# Having difficulty to install git using Homebrew

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

I am watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUviVWnvBM8) to install git using Homebrew. I already got Homebrew installed. The problem i have is installing git using Homebrew. I typed brew install git and have certain error message.

Error msg:

```
./generate-cmdlist.sh > common-cmds.h+ && mv common-cmds.h+ common-cmds.h
/usr/bin/xcrun clang -o hex.o -c -MF ./.depend/hex.o.d -MMD -MP  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -I. -DUSE_ST_TIMESPEC -DNO_GETTEXT  -DHAVE_DEV_TTY -DSHA1_HEADER='<openssl/sha.h>'  -DNO_MEMMEM  hex.c
/usr/bin/xcrun clang -o ident.o -c -MF ./.depend/ident.o.d -MMD -MP  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -I. -DUSE_ST_TIMESPEC -DNO_GETTEXT  -DHAVE_DEV_TTY -DSHA1_HEADER='<openssl/sha.h>'  -DNO_MEMMEM  ident.c
/usr/bin/xcrun clang -o kwset.o -c -MF ./.depend/kwset.o.d -MMD -MP  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -I. -DUSE_ST_TIMESPEC -DNO_GETTEXT  -DHAVE_DEV_TTY -DSHA1_HEADER='<openssl/sha.h>'  -DNO_MEMMEM  kwset.c
In file included from ident.c:8:
In file included from ./cache.h:4:
./git-compat-util.h:93:10: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#include <unistd.h>
         ^
In file included from hex.c:1:
In file included from ./cache.h:4:
./git-compat-util.h:93:10: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#include <unistd.h>
         ^
In file included from kwset.c:37:
In file included from ./cache.h:4:
./git-compat-util.h:93:10: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#include <unistd.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [hex.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [ident.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make: *** [kwset.o] Error 1
==> Build Environment
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
MacOS: 10.7.4-x86_64
Xcode: 4.3.2
CC: /usr/bin/xcrun clang => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

CXX: /usr/bin/xcrun clang++ => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++

LD: /usr/bin/xcrun clang => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments
CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
Error: Failed executing: make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.10.3 CC=/usr/bin/xcrun\ clang CFLAGS=-Os\ -w\ -pipe\ -march=native\ -Qunused-arguments LDFLAGS= install (git.rb:49)
These existing issues may help you:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8643
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9023
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9618
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10544
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11481
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12325
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12344
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12400
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12478
Otherwise, please report the bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/reporting-bugs
```

How do i solve this error? Need some help

Comment: Have you installed the Command-line tools? You can do that through Xcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must install the command-line tools through Xcode to get the needed headers.

Comment: Isn't there a way to specify the search path for git, e.g. environmental variable for `brew`?

Comment: The command line tools are available under Preferences/Downloads in XCode 4.4.

Comment: **How can you see that you have installed those commands in XCode 5?** I see only this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-14%20at%2022.17.44.png

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to [download it](http://git-scm.com/download/mac). Also, if you use github, I suggest you to just read [this page](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/). One year ago I started in this way.